# How to communicate between two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, monitoring

I have 2 threads managed by JBoss (without start method). I need that if one of them enters into a loop then the other one has to be able to kill it. In other words, how can I send a message (or exception) from one thread to the other? Is there a way to communicate between independent threads?

Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish, here?

Comment: ...because forcibly killing another thread almost always is a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways to use a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). You will have to initialize the queue in your main thread. I have an example below that writes to a blocking queue and shows how to read from a blocking queue in your threads. This example can easily be adapted to read/write to the blocking queue from within your threads. If you want to shut down your thread you can write a sentinel value to the blocking queue that your thread, when read, could shut down.

The main Driver:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // A blocking queue used to pass strings to threads
    BlockingQueue<Entry<String> sharedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue< String>();

    // The number of cores available on the running machine
    // Note: if Hyper Threading is enabled this will be double the number of
    // physical cores
    int numCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    // Create a thread pool of size equal to numCores
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numCores);

    // Initialize all of the Tasks and add them to the thread pool
    for (int i = 0; i < numCores; i++) {
        Runnable task = new WellFormedStringRunnable(sharedQueue);
        threadPool.execute(task);
    }

    // Do not allow any more tasks to be added and wait for all tasks to be
    // completed before shutting down the executor
    threadPool.shutdown();

    // Read form STDIN and add each line to the shared queue
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {

        // The current line
        String input;

        // Continue processing until a null character has been reached
        while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // Add the tuple (line number, string) to the shared queue
            try {
                sharedQueue.put(input);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("Error accessing shared queue: "
                        + e.getMessage());
                threadPool.shutdownNow();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error reading from STDIN: " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }


    // Allow all threads to complete
    try {
        threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        // If the shared queue throws an exception, display the error and
        // shutdown all running tasks
        System.err.println("Error while waiting for threads to terminate: "
                + e.getMessage());
        threadPool.shutdownNow();
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

The thread code:

```
public class RunnableThread implements Runnable {

    /** A blocking queue used to retrieve strings */
    private final BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue;

    public RunnableThread(BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue) {
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Used to hold a value from the shared queue
        String currValue = null;

        // Continue to process strings while the thread is not interrupted and
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                // Get a string from the shared queue
                currValue = this.sharedQueue.take();

                // Process Strings
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```